# Get single post id from json file in NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

How to get the single post id data from json file in NuxtJS?

```
created() {
    this.getProductsData()
},
methods: {
    getProductsData() {
        const vm = this
        this.$axios
            .get(`/json/products.json`)
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.item = response.data.products
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a single post, or get the id for all of them?

Comment: I want to get the single post because I have the all the data already

Comment: What about `let postId = response.data.products[0]._id` ?

Comment: I'm getting the first of the json right now but how can I get the right id with the right URL?

Comment: I think we are missing some information here. Can you paste some more of your code and elaborate a bit on the problem?

Comment: So do you want to retrieve a post by its id, så lets say you want the post where `_id === "spekkoek-panden"`?

Comment: @Djip yes exactly like that! would you know how to get the specific id?

Answer (score 0):

To get a post from a specific id, you could filter the data based on their `_id`, and then take the first entry returned (as there should only be one with the unique :

```
methods: {
    getProductsData() {
        const vm = this
        this.$axios
            .get(`/json/products.json`)
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.item = response.data.products.filter((item) => {
                    return item._id === 'spekkoek-panden';
                })[0]
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
}
```